# JavaScript Class Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, onload

I am trying to build a JavaScript class, and I am having problems with this line:
`this.ctx.drawImage(img.src, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);`

The error message that shows up is: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'drawImage' of undefined**

```
function jraw(id){
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.setImage = function(url){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = function(){
            this.ctx.drawImage(img.src, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        };
    };
}
```

I then call it like so:

```
<script>
    var j = new jraw("canvas");
    j.setImage("/images/my_image.jpg");
</script>
```

How do I get the onload to access the `ctx` property? I did some testing, and it sees the ctx property in the setImage method, but not the onload method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
this.setImage = function(url){
    var that = this;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function(){
        that.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    };
};
```

Also the first param to [.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images#drawImage) is the image object, not the `url`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qh7rp/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option:

```
function jraw(id){
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    var that = this;
    this.setImage = function(url){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = function(){
            that.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        };
   };
}
```

Though not necessary the best one.

Comment: on which line, what are the values of the locals at that moment?

Comment: it is exactly the same as what you have

Comment: what do you mean? also Arun's answer does pretty much the same thing so it is all good anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that this is something different in your onload function than it is in your setImage method. When this is used with a method it will be bound to the object the function/method is a part of when it is a function it is bound to the global object.

You'll want to set this to a variable outside the onload method or access the global object (almost always the window object) from within the onload method.